# java algorithm calculation of precision

Tags: java, algorithm

```
/**
 * @(#)precision1.java
 *
 * precision1 application
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2013/11/15
 */

public class precision1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO, add your application code

        int x = 4;
        double increment = 1 ;
        double coefficient = 1;
        double currentValue = 1;
        double precision = 0.01;

        for( int i = 1;increment>precision ;i++)
        {
            currentValue= Math.pow(x,i)*coefficient+currentValue;
            increment= Math.abs (Math.pow(x,i)*coefficient);
            coefficient = coefficient * (1/(i+1));
            System.out.println("Current result: " + currentValue);
        }

    }
}
```

The question is:  If number 2 is given, it should ask an integer x from user, and a precision. It should calculate approximate value of e to the power x by using the formula given below, by using user inputted x. Your program stops calculation whenever the increment is less than given precision value. It should also be written as a method, not directly in your main method.
[image: the formula]

and the output should be:

```
current result: 5.0
current result: 13.0
current result: 23.666666666666664
current result: 34.33333333333333
current result: 42.86666666666666
current result: 48.55555555555555
current result: 51.8063492063492
current result: 53.43174603174603
current result: 54.15414462081129
current result: 54.44310405643739
current result: 54.54818021484688
current result: 54.583205600983376
current result: 54.59398264287153
current result: 54.59706179769672
Result is 54.59706179769672
```

and output of my code is:

```
Current result: 5.0
Current result: 5.0
```

Regardless of asking input parts why my code does not work?

Comment: Well, what do you get in your program? (i.e. what specifically about it doesn't work?)

Comment: it outputs
current result: 5.0
current result: 5.0
then stop.

Comment: Can you put that in the question description too? It'll help in case comments get cluttered/deleted.

Comment: Two things - it seems the formula given has constraints on x - it has to be in the range (-1,1), and you aren't alternating the sign of the coefficient.

Comment: Before asking someone here to help, you should have at least stepped through the code in an IDE debugger to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry I got confused now I editted and wrote the true question .

Comment: there is a logic error I assume but I cannot find it

Comment: You don't need to calculate *Math.pow(x,i)*coefficient* twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly running it through a debugger - 
`(1/(i+1))`is integer division, causing `coefficient = coefficient * (1/(i+1));`
to evaluate to 0 and thus
 `increment= Math.abs (Math.pow(x,i)*coefficient);` 
to evaluate to 0

Answer (score 0):

Your coefficient is wrong. You should just set it to 1/(1+i). Along with the fact that you use ints as other users spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is integer division in the expression `1/(i+1)` - this will evaluate to 0 for any `i >=2`.

I suggest you change

```
coefficient = coefficient * (1/(i+1));
```

to

```
coefficient = coefficient / (i+1);
```

or even just

```
coefficient /= i + 1;
```

which will both evaluate correctly, since `coefficient` is double.

Answer (score 0):

You numbers are defined as integers, not double.

```
for (int i = 1; increment > precision; i++) {
    currentValue = Math.pow(x, i) * coefficient + currentValue;
    increment = Math.abs(Math.pow(x, i) * coefficient);
    coefficient = coefficient * (1d / (i + 1d)); // here is fix

    System.out.println("Current result: " + currentValue);
}
```